# `protoc` generating invalid Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a bunch of `.proto` files and the root one defines:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
package com.example;
```

and `import`s some of the others.

Using `gradlew generateProto` produces invalid Java files with contents like:

```
        new com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor[] {
          .AnotherOuterClass.getDescriptor(),
        }, assigner);
```

This causes compilation errors like:

```
…/SomeOuterClass.java:1337: error: illegal start of expression
          .AnotherOuterClass.getDescriptor(),
```

What needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `package com.example;` to all the other `.proto` files.

Doing so will generate code like:

```
        new com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor[] {
          com.example.AnotherOuterClass.getDescriptor(),
        }, assigner);
```